# Infinite Loop /Segmentation error

Tags: c, file, hashtable, phrase

Getting an infinite loop, but when I try to "//" out two loops I start getting fseek() seg error...

Purpose of file...: To find common phrases (groupings of words) between files.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define CONTENTS 20000
#define MAXFILES 30
#include "hash.h"


void printOutput(int numFiles, int output[30][30])
{
  int i, j;
 //print output matrix
 for (i = 0; i < numFiles; i++){
    printf("f%d    ", i + 1); // print upper row of file names, use 4 spaces
 }

 for (i = 0; i < numFiles; i++){
    if (i > 8) // if file marker is 2 digits, use 2 spaces
    {
        printf("f%d  ", i + 1); // print upper row of file names
    }
  else printf("f%d   ", i + 1); // else file marker is 1 digit, use 3 spaces

  printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < numFiles; j++){
        // the following if else statements manage the spacing for various numbers, soley for aesthetic purposes
        if (output[i][j] == 45){ // print the dash character
            printf("%c     ", output[i][j]); // use 5 spaces
            continue;
        }
        else if (output[i][j] > 9 && output[i][j] < 100){ // if 2 digit number, 4 spaces
            printf("%d    ", output[i][j]);
            continue;
        }
        else if (output[i][j] > 99 && output[i][j] < 1000){ // if 3 digit number, 3 spaces
            printf("%d   ", output[i][j]);
            continue;
        }

        else if (output[i][j] > 999 && output[i][j] < 10000){ // if 4 digit number, 2 spaces
            printf("%d  ", output[i][j]);
            continue;
        }
        else if (output[i][j] > 9999){ // if 5 digit number, 1 space
            printf("%d ", output[i][j]);
            continue;
        }
        else printf("%d     ", output[i][j]); // 1 digit number, 5 spaces
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int group_length, valid;
  int list[30];
  //Range checking
  while( valid == 0 ) 
 {
    printf("What is the number of words to analyze (2 - 10)?\n");
    scanf("%d",&group_length);

    if( (group_length < 2) || (group_length > 10) )
       printf("\n");
    else
        valid = 1;
   }

  struct node * Map[30];
  int f;
  for(f = 0; f < 30; f++)
  {
     Map[f] = createHash(2000);
  }

  FILE *fp;
  int i, numberF = 0;
  int output[30][30]; // upper triangular output matrix
  char name[CONTENTS];
  char fnames[CONTENTS];
  fp = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
  char *names = malloc(sizeof *names);
  int *SequenceList = malloc(sizeof *SequenceList);
  //int *SequenceList  malloc(MAXFILES * sizeof(int *));
  int seq; //Sequence
 char entireFile[CONTENTS];
 char *wordArray[CONTENTS];
 char *token2, *search = " \r\n\t";

 for (i = 0; fgets(name, 100, fp) != NULL && i < MAXFILES; i++) 
 {
    ++numberF;
    char *token = NULL; //setting to nukl before using it to strtok
    token = strtok(name, ":");
    strtok(token, "\n");//Getting rid of that dirty \n that I hate
    strcat(&fnames[i], token);
    //Part 2:
    FILE *fpp;
    fpp = fopen(fnames,"r");
    fseek(fpp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int inputLength = ftell(fpp);
    rewind(fpp);
    //Reads data from a given stream into an array pointed to
    fread(entireFile, inputLength, 1, fpp);
    fclose(fpp); 
   //Closing file
   token2 = strtok(entireFile, search); 
   seq = 0;
   //wordArray[seq] = token2;
   char temp[CONTENTS];

   while (token2 != NULL)
   {
      while(seq < group_length)
     {
         token2 = strtok(NULL, search);
         wordArray[seq] = token2;
         strcpy(temp, wordArray[seq]);
         insertHash(Map[i], temp, SequenceList[i]);
         seq++;
         //output[i] = Map[i]->counts[i];
     }
    }//End of token2 NULL loop

   } 

    //closing  inputfile.txt... Presuming now is best time
   fclose(fp);

   //Printing and calling printOutput function
   int k, l;
  for (k = 0; k < 30; k++)
      for (l = 0; l < 30; l++)
         output[k][l] = 45;       
  printOutput(numberF, output);

return 0;
```

}

Snippet of exactly what I'm talking about...:

```
FILE *fpp;
  fpp = fopen(fnames,"r");
  fseek(fpp, 0, SEEK_END);
   int inputLength = ftell(fpp);
  rewind(fpp);
  //Reads data from a given stream into an array pointed to
   fread(entireFile, inputLength, 1, fpp);
   fclose(fpp); 
  //Closing file
  token2 = strtok(entireFile, search); 
   seq = 0;
   //wordArray[seq] = token2;
  char temp[CONTENTS];

  while (token2 != NULL)
  {
     while(seq < group_length)
    {
        token2 = strtok(NULL, search);
          wordArray[seq] = token2;
        strcpy(temp, wordArray[seq]);
        insertHash(Map[i], temp, SequenceList[i]);
        seq++;
        //output[i] = Map[i]->counts[i];
     }
    }//End of token2 NULL lo
```

Code of my hash.c (Made sure it never expires and is public): http://pastebin.com/Cz4R7WwK //Updated
its header: http://pastebin.com/ex2zARGt

Edit:
Getting a new seg error after latest of additions..
Getting seg error with the cmp part of my insertHash in hash.c
Here are the warnings in insertHash

```
scratch_Hash.c: In function ‘insertHash’:
scratch_Hash.c:47:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘hash’ discards ‘const’ qual    ifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
ha = hash(info)%200;
^
 scratch_Hash.c:31:15: note: expected ‘unsigned char *’ but argument is of type      const char *’
 unsigned long hash(unsigned char *str)
                      ^
 scratch_Hash.c:57:12: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enable    d by default]
   node = node->next;
        ^
 scratch_Hash.c:64:18: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enable    d by default]
newNode->next = table[ha];
```

First two I can do later but worried about incompatile pointer type. How do I solve that in this case?

direct spot where seg error is...:

```
  while(node != NULL)
  {
    if (strcmp(node->data,info) == 0)
    {    
      node->counts[file]++;  
      return node;  
    }
   node = node->next;
}
```

Comment: Adding warnings when you compile will help you

Comment: Once seq == group_length the outer while loop runs forever.  Why is it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with allocations.  In your `struct node` definition you have

```
int   counts[30];
```

but when you `createHash(2000)` you are accessing up to counts[1999].  You probably intend to make counts a pointer like

```
int *counts;
```

and allocate it in createHash

```
newTable->counts = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
```

Furthermore, your allocations on the heap are only allocating enough memory for a pointer and not the struct itself.  For example in hash.c

```
struct node * newTable = malloc(sizeof *newTable);
```

will allocate enough memory for a pointer, not for a `struct node`.  You probably want to instead use

```
struct node * newTable = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

For the infinite loop issue, the first argument of insertHash is of type `struct node**` but you pass a `struct node*`.  You want to use

```
insertHash(Map, ...
```

The compiler warnings should indicate those issues.  Lastly, in your `node` definition, you define

```
struct Node *next;
```

but you want

```
struct node *next;
```

Comment: Yeah I probably should just make it size 30... Because I really just need 30. I was accidently putting how many characters number instead of max files for creating the createHash for counts. So I'll just leave at int counts[30]. Thank you. Sorry for stupid silly errors like the struct node *next. didn't catch it. And with the insertHash(map...) not insertHash(map[i],...) that seemed to get rid of that one warning but would with how i have it written still get what I desire by that way?
when I do in createHash struct node * newTable = maloc(sizeof(node)); I get a error saying node undeclared

Comment: Fixed: struct node * newTable = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

Comment: Updated the answer with the missing struct too.  You would need to make other changes to make insertHash(Map,... work, like passing i.  You can also change the function declaration to insertHash(struct node* node,...) which will handle calling insertHash(Map[i],...)

Comment: If I were to change it to insertHash(struct node* **table, ...) then I wouldn't have to worry about passing the i?

Comment: Yes (change to struct node *table)